# How to monitor if file changed externally in Monaco editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

Is there an API for listening external file changes in Monaco editor?

I am developing a react application and my solution is to keep the current modal as a state and use the `onDidChangeContent` event to compare the current model for any changes.

Is this a better approach or what could be the best approach for listing external changes to load them to the editor?

Answer (score 0):

You could check it using `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` functions and AJAX. Each second you can load your file and compare it with the last loaded file content in Monaco editor. If the file content is not the same then load it again or ask a user before about it.